# How to have a setter in an object?

Tags: scala

I am trying to add a setter method in an object:

```
object Foo {
  def foo_=(s: String) = println(s) 
}

Foo.foo = "test"
```

This does not work as expected, and compiler complains about "value foo is not a member of object Foo".

Why does it not work? How can I make it work, other than make a setter method without `_=`?

Comment: Why not simply `var foo: String = ""`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez because I need to process the variable after setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work just right in **Scala** `2.13`

```
object Foo {
  private var f: String = ""

  def foo_=(s: String): Unit =
    this.f = s.toLowerCase

  def foo: String =
    this.f
}
```

You can check like following.

```
Foo.foo
// res: String = ""

Foo.foo = "HELLO"

Foo.foo
// res: String = "hello"
```

Comment: Looks like 2.12.9 fixed it. It was broken with the version I was using 2.12.8.

Answer (score 0):

Scala only recognizes this method as a setter if you have a getter `def foo = ...` as well:

> [If `x` is a parameterless method defined in some template, and the same template contains a setter method `x_=` as member, then the assignment `x = e` is interpreted as the invocation `x_=(e)` of that setter method.](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#assignments)

From your comment:

> Looks like 2.12.9 fixed it. It was broken with the version I was using 2.12.8.

Testing at https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8uAu5WCAQJa3darpMkCidg, I get the expected result: without a getter it fails in both 2.12.8 and 2.13.1, with one it works in both.